# How to securely get access token from Marketo

Tags: c#, rest, security, http, marketo

Marketo Rest API exposes a GET call to oauth/token uri, which exposes clientId and clientSecret parameters to all internet hops between the 2 networks. Am I missing something or is there a way we can securely get an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got my facts wrong, basically this get call is https, and query parameters will be sent encrypted over the wire once it establishes a secure connection to the server. Only caveat I found is that a server admin can read the credentials in clear text if browsed server file system which is a low risk.

Answer (score 0):

Marketo also has a POST method for this endpoint where you can send the clientId and clientSecret as x-www-form-urlencoded POST parameters

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials' "https://MY_MARKETO_URL/identity/oauth/token"`

Comment: This is not their in their documentation, however it does work as expected and returns a valid access_token